# Android testing fragments and login action

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, junit

Hi guys i'm trying to test my android app.It is an app used for the restaurant industry similar to just eat for example.
I've done some testing on generic navigation and now I want to test the login action and see if the fragments are loaded.

This is my test class

```
 @Test
    fun test_Login_to_FragmentRistoranti(){
        //Setup activity scenario
        val activityScenario= ActivityScenario.launch(IntroActivity::class.java)
        //Perform click action per andare a LogIn
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.ConstraintLogin))
            .check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()))
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.ConstraintLogin)).perform(ViewActions.click())
        
        //login action user livello 1
        val email:String="useruser@gmail.com"
        val pwd:String="useruser"

        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.email)).perform(ViewActions.typeText(email))
        closeSoftKeyboard()
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.password)).perform(ViewActions.typeText(pwd))
        closeSoftKeyboard()
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.ConstraintLogin)).perform(ViewActions.click())
        //Controllo dopo il login che si veda fragmentRistoranti
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.swipe_refresh_ristoranti))
            .check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()))
        
        //logout e controllo che si veda login
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.ic_logoutU)).perform(ViewActions.click())
        //Perform click action per andare a LogIn
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.ConstraintLogin))
            .check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()))
        
    }
```

And this is my FragmentLogin class

```
package com.example.progettoprogrammazione.intro

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import com.example.progettoprogrammazione.R
import com.example.progettoprogrammazione.activity.EmployeeActivity
import com.example.progettoprogrammazione.activity.RestaurateurActivity
import com.example.progettoprogrammazione.activity.UserActivity
import com.example.progettoprogrammazione.databinding.Fragment0LoginBinding
import com.example.progettoprogrammazione.firebase.FireBaseCallbackRestaurant
import com.example.progettoprogrammazione.firebase.FireBaseCallbackCart
import com.example.progettoprogrammazione.firebase.FireBaseCallbackUser
import com.example.progettoprogrammazione.utils.*
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase

// Made by Alessandro Pieragostini, Matteo Sonaglioni & Stefano Marcucci
/* Chi utilizza questo fragment può accedere all'interno dell'applicazione, a seconda del livello
 utente, oppure navigare alla pagina Registrati */


class FragmentLogin : Fragment(), UserUtils, DipendenteUtils, RestaurantUtils, ProductUtils,
    CartUtils {
private lateinit var binding: Fragment0LoginBinding
override var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
override var firebaseDatabase: FirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()

private var userlvl: String? = null
private lateinit var useremail: String

fun login(email:String, password:String){

    if (email.isNotEmpty() && password.isNotEmpty()) {
        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {

                //LOGIN
                getUserData(object : FireBaseCallbackUser {
                    override fun onResponse(responseU: ResponseUser) {
                        userlvl = responseU.user!!.Livello

                        Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            "Login effettuato con successo!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        )
                            .show()

                        getQRData(
                            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid,
                            object : FireBaseCallbackCart {
                                override fun onResponse(responseC: ResponseCart) {
                                    getRestaurantData(object : FireBaseCallbackRestaurant {
                                        override fun onResponse(responseR: ResponseRistorante) {

                                            when (userlvl) {
                                                "1" -> {
                                                    val intent =
                                                        Intent(
                                                            context,
                                                            UserActivity::class.java
                                                        ).apply {
                                                            putExtra("user", responseU.user)
                                                            putParcelableArrayListExtra(
                                                                "ristoranti",
                                                                responseR.ristoranti
                                                            )
                                                            putExtra(
                                                                "cart",
                                                                responseC.cart
                                                            )
                                                        }
                                                    startActivity(intent)
                                                    activity?.finish()
                                                }

                                                "2" -> {

                                                    val intent =
                                                        Intent(
                                                            context,
                                                            EmployeeActivity::class.java
                                                        ).apply {
                                                            putExtra("user", responseU.user)
                                                            putParcelableArrayListExtra(
                                                                "ristoranti",
                                                                responseR.ristoranti
                                                            )
                                                            putExtra(
                                                                "cart",
                                                                responseC.cart
                                                            )
                                                        }
                                                    startActivity(intent)
                                                    activity?.finish()
                                                }

                                                "3" -> {

                                                    val intent =
                                                        Intent(
                                                            context,
                                                            RestaurateurActivity::class.java
                                                        ).apply {
                                                            putExtra("user", responseU.user)
                                                            putParcelableArrayListExtra(
                                                                "ristoranti",
                                                                responseR.ristoranti
                                                            )
                                                            putExtra(
                                                                "cart",
                                                                responseC.cart
                                                            )
                                                        }
                                                    startActivity(intent)
                                                    activity?.finish()

                                                }
                                                else -> {
                                                    Toast.makeText(
                                                        context,
                                                        "Errore durante il caricamento.",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                                    ).show()
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }, context)
                                }
                            },
                            context
                        )
                    }
                }, context)

            } else Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "Email e password non corrispondono!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Nessun campo può essere vuoto!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show()
    }
}
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    binding = Fragment0LoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    // Questa funzione permette di effettuare il login quando i campi di email e password corrispondono
    // ad un account già creato e, a seconda del livello, si effettuerà la navigazione in una delle Activity
    binding.ConstraintLogin.setOnClickListener {
        login( binding.email.text.toString(), binding.password.text.toString())
    }

    // Cliccando in questo bottone, verrà mandata una mail di recupero password
    binding.recuperapassword.setOnClickListener {
        useremail = binding.email.text.toString()
        if (useremail.isNotEmpty()) {
            recoverUserPassword(context, useremail)
        } else Toast.makeText(context, "Inserisci un'email.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }

    // Cliccando sul bottone, la navigazione porterà alla pagina "Registrati"
    binding.noaccount.setOnClickListener {
        view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.LoginToRegister)
    }

}
```

}

The error of the test class is reported below

```
androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: 

view.getId() is <2131362204/com.example.progettoprogrammazione:id/email>

View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=2280, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params={(0,0)(fillxfill) ty=BASE_APPLICATION wanim=0x10302fe
fl=LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR SPLIT_TOUCH HARDWARE_ACCELERATED DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS
pfl=NO_MOVE_ANIMATION FORCE_DRAW_STATUS_BAR_BACKGROUND FIT_INSETS_CONTROLLED
bhv=DEFAULT
fitSides=}, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}
|
+->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=2214, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+-->ViewStub{id=16908746, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-->FrameLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=2148, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=66.0, child-count=1}
|
+--->ActionBarOverlayLayout{id=2131362158, res-name=decor_content_parent, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=2148, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+---->ContentFrameLayout{id=16908290, res-name=content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1994, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=154.0, child-count=1}
|
+----->ConstraintLayout{id=2131362320, res-name=intro_activity, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1994, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+------>FragmentContainerView{id=2131362417, res-name=nav_host, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1994, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+------->FragmentContainerView{id=2131362417, res-name=nav_host, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1994, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+-------->ConstraintLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1994, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+--------->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1994, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=4}
|
+---------->AppCompatImageView{id=2131362307, res-name=image_intro, visibility=VISIBLE, width=871, height=871, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=104.0, y=55.0}
|
+---------->MaterialTextView{id=2131361945, res-name=benvenuto_text, visibility=VISIBLE, width=720, height=88, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=180.0, y=926.0, text=Benvenuto su Cookade!, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+---------->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=970, height=279, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=55.0, y=1152.0, child-count=1}
|
+----------->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=936, height=279, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=17.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+------------>ConstraintLayout{id=2131361801, res-name=ConstraintLogin, visibility=VISIBLE, width=550, height=138, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=193.0, y=55.0, child-count=1}
|
+------------->MaterialTextView{id=2131362346, res-name=login, visibility=VISIBLE, width=163, height=71, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=194.0, y=34.0, text=LOGIN, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------------>MaterialTextView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=826, height=3, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=55.0, y=221.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+---------->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=970, height=127, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=55.0, y=1431.0, child-count=1}
|
+----------->MaterialTextView{id=2131362547, res-name=registrati, visibility=VISIBLE, width=914, height=71, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=28.0, y=28.0, text=Non sei registrato? Clicca qui!, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+---->ActionBarContainer{id=2131361899, res-name=action_bar_container, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=154, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+----->Toolbar{id=2131361897, res-name=action_bar, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=154, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+------>AppCompatTextView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=269, height=71, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=44.0, y=41.0, text=COOKADE, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------>ActionMenuView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=154, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=1080.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}
|
+----->ActionBarContextView{id=2131361905, res-name=action_context_bar, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}
|
+->View{id=16908336, res-name=navigationBarBackground, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=66, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=2214.0}
|
+->View{id=16908335, res-name=statusBarBackground, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=66, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
at androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException$Builder.build(NoMatchingViewException.java:5)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.lambda$getNoMatchingViewExceptionTruncater$0(DefaultFailureHandler.java:5)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.truncateExceptionMessage(Unknown Source:2)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.ViewHierarchyExceptionHandler.handleSafely(ViewHierarchyExceptionHandler.java:5)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.ViewHierarchyExceptionHandler.handleSafely(ViewHierarchyExceptionHandler.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$TypedFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:4)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:5)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:8)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:11)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:8)
at com.example.progettoprogrammazione.UserNavigationTesting.test_Login_to_FragmentRistoranti(UserNavigationTesting.kt:46)
```

Now I want to ask a couple of questions:
1)Why my test returns failed
2)How can i test my login logic in a better way. We use in our project firebase realtimedb and i do not know how to implement testing (like i want to test if i let the user text view blank , ecc)
3)Where i can do some simple testing and not UI tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is failing because after the click action on R.id.ConstraintLogin, the  expected view is not showing on the screen. This could be due to a number of reasons, such as due to the fragment/activity loading is taking longer than the test or that the view does not contain the click listener. You would have to share a little more code for me to be able to pinpoint the problem. I would also suggest looking into Idling resources if its due to a timing issue.

If you want to test your own logic better, then you will need to extract the code parts that are your own logic into separate functions for unit testing. Testing against a DB is not a good idea, instead you should mock the data and make the data access layer abstract for testing purposes.

Simple testing is done with unit tests, here you can test data classes and functions, but beware, you have no android context without using a framework such as mockjay or mockito.